# I have a non-performant method, how can I improve its efficiency?

Tags: c#, performance, time-complexity

I have a simple method to compare an array of FileInfo objects against a list of filenames to check what files have been already been processed. The unprocessed list is then returned.

The loop of this method iterates for about 250,000 FileInfo objects. This is taking an obscene amount of time to compete.

The inefficiency is obviously the Contains method call on the processedFiles collection.

First how can I check to make sure my suspicion is true about the cause and secondly, how can I improve the method to speed the process up?

```
public static List<FileInfo> GetUnprocessedFiles(FileInfo[] allFiles, List<string> processedFiles)
{
List<FileInfo> unprocessedFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in allFiles)
{
    if (!processedFiles.Contains(fileInfo.Name))
    {
        unprocessedFiles.Add(fileInfo);
    }
    }
    return unprocessedFiles;
}
```

Comment: For (1) use a decent profiler, e.g. DotTrace from JetBrains (free trial available).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `List<T>`'s `Contains` method runs in linear time, since it potentially has to enumerate the entire list to prove the existence / non-existence of an item. I would suggest you use a`HashSet<string>` or similar instead. A [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)'s `Contains`method is designed to run in constant `O(1)` time, i.e it shouldn't depend on the number of items in the set.

This small change should make the entire method run in linear time:

```
public static List<FileInfo> GetUnprocessedFiles(FileInfo[] allFiles, 
                                         List<string> processedFiles)
{
   List<FileInfo> unprocessedFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
   HashSet<string> processedFileSet = new HashSet<string>(processedFiles);

   foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in allFiles)
   {
       if (!processedFileSet.Contains(fileInfo.Name))
       {
           unprocessedFiles.Add(fileInfo);
       }
    }

   return unprocessedFiles;
}
```

I would suggest 3 improvements, if possible:

1. For *extra* efficiency, store the processed files in a set *at the source*, so that this method takes an `ISet<T>` as a parameter. This way, you won't have to reconstruct the set every time.
2. Try not to mix and match different representations of the *same* entity  (`string` and `FileInfo`) in this fashion. Pick one and go with it.
3. You might also want to consider the `HashSet<T>.ExceptWith` method instead of doing the looping yourself. Bear in mind that this will mutate the collection.

If you can use LINQ, and you can afford to build up a set on every call, here's another way:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetUnprocessedFiles
 (IEnumerable<string> allFiles, IEnumerable<string> processedFiles)
{
  // null-checks here
  return allFiles.Except(processedFiles);     
}
```

Comment: +1; does that mean that allFiles.Except(processedFiles) creates Map first in its implementation?

Comment: @chiccodoro: Yes that's right. Looking at the code in reflector, it currently appears to be implemented using an internal class called `Set<T>` rather than a `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: The reason for the mismatch between FileInfo[] and HashSet<string> is the source of processedFiles is a .txt file and the source of allFiles is the method DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(). Wouldn’t the conversion for the FileInfo array be extra unnecessary load?

Comment: @Anthony: Ah, I see. Well, I guess it depends on what sort of efficiency you need. It's just a single pass of the array to do the projection, so unless that's a problem, I would go with it. To be honest, I think  the `FileInfo` type is a pain to deal with in collections it doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. So if you don't want to project, you'll probably have to write your own `IEqalityComparer<T>` implementation, such as the one here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx

Comment: The performance level I require at the current number of files has been met with the changes you have suggested. I have now changed the method to body to contain one line: return new HashSet<string>(allFiles.Except(processedFiles)); with a view to providing good efficiency in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to convert the processedFiles List to a HashSet. With a list, it needs to iterate the list everytime you call contains. A HashSet is an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary/hastable like class to speed up the lookup process significantly. Even translation the incoming List into an hashtable once, then using that one will be much quicker than what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the searched array by file name
2. employ `Array.BinarySearch<T>()` to search the array. This should come out at about O(logN) efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

to check if a list contains an element is faster with a sorted list

Answer (score 0):

Just to be excessively pedantic ...

If you know that both lists are sorted (FileInfo lists often come pre-sorted, so this approach might be applicable to you), then you can achieve true linear performance without the time and memory overhead of a hashset. Hashset construction still requires linear time to build, so complexity is closer to O(n + m); the hashset has to internally allocate additional object references for at most 250k strings in your case and that's going to cost in GC terms.

Something like this half-baked generalisation might help:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetMismatches(IList<string> fileNames, IList<string> processedFileNames, StringComparer comparer)
    {
        var filesIndex = 0;
        var procFilesIndex = 0;

        while (filesIndex < fileNames.Count)
        {
            if (procFilesIndex >= processedFileNames.Count)
            {
                yield return files[filesIndex++];
            }
            else
            {
                var rc = comparer.Compare(fileNames[filesIndex], processedFileNames[procFilesIndex]);
                if (rc != 0)
                {
                    if (rc < 0)
                    {
                        yield return files[filesIndex++];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        procFilesIndex++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    filesIndex++;
                    procFilesIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

        yield break;
    }
```

I would strongly agree with Ani that sticking to a generic or canonical type is A Very Good Thing Indeed.
But I'll give mine  -1 for unfinished generalisation and -1 for elegance...